# python3 - request - cookie -

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

How can i get cookie of last page with?

My codes are here:

```
headerMain = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125"}
istekMain = requests.get("https://www.example.org/", headers=headerMain)

cookie = istekMain.cookies.get_dict()
istekLazim = {"display_type":"popup"}
istekLogin = requests.get("https://www.example.org/", headers=headerMain, params=istekLazim, cookies=cookie)
print(istekLogin.text)
```